# Nature's Police - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, science

I pull you down, I'm nature's police

I've been with you since birth, and you I'll never release

You have to obey me, you have no choice

I'm also invisible and I make no noise.

Some one found me, under a tree

Some one found me, who could they be?

What am I?

Hint 1:

> Apple

Hint 2:

> Law

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> Gravity, quite simple from the Apple :)

Comment: You should put your answer into a spoiler tag to obscure it from others (with >! at the start of the line) as I have edited.